# Erro: the right syntax to use near 'add

Tags: php, mysql

Não sei o que está acontecendo mas o meu codigo não funciona
ele simplesmente não está inserindo dados na tabela

```
<?php
include "../../lib/inc_con.php";
session_start();
$mesa = $_POST['mesa'];
$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$quantidade = $_POST['qtd'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
$hiddentotal = $_POST['hiddentotal'];
$data = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$produto_id1 = $_POST['produto_id1'];
$atendente_id = $_SESSION['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, add, hiddentotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id) values ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$add', '$hiddentotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$atendente_id')") or die (mysql_error());

?>
```

caso necessário aqui está minha tabela

[image: TABELA PEDIDOS]

E aqui está o erro que está exibindo na tela

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'add, hiddentotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id) values ('6',
>   '14.25', '2', '1' at line 1

Comment: pela mensagem de erro vc não consegue deduzir nada?

Comment: Depois de uma olhada nesse post : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: use mysqli_* ou PDO, o mysql* está sendo descontinuado nas novas versões do PHP 5.4.

Comment: Se resolveu não esqueça de aceitar a resposta que foi mais útil para você, também veja [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é `add` é uma [palavra reservada do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html) então é necessário escapar nomes de colunas ou tabelas com backsticks.

O `add` normalmente é visto dessa forma:

```
ALTER TABLE <nome> ADD COLUMN <nome> ...
```

Consulta corrigida:

```
INSERT INTO pedidos (mesa, tamanho, qtd, `add`, hiddentotal, data, produto_id1, atendente_id)
 values ('$mesa', '$tamanho', '$quantidade', '$add', '$hiddentotal', '$data', '$produto_id1', '$atendente_id')"
```

Answer (score 3):

O erro encontra-se na entrada de sua coluna **data** no MySQL.
 Sua coluna **data** está com o tipo definido `date`, logo este tipo aceita valores de entrada no formato `yyyy-mm-dd` e sua variável `$data` está tentando passar para esta coluna o valor de `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s`.

**2 opções para correção:**

> 1. Mude o valor de sua variável para `date('Y-m-d')`

ou

> 2. Mude o tipo de sua coluna **data** no MySQL de `date` para `datetime`, assim poderá receber o valor no formato que está tentando passar.

[MySQL Reference Manual > Data Types > Date and Time Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html)

Comment: Na verdade isso é indiferente, porque a tabela captura apenas os valores da data e ignora os da hora, e o erro não é resportado aí, está no quarto valor.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, realmente deve-se à utilização da palavra reservada 'add', quanto à data, convém alterar o campo na base de dados para datetime, caso contrário não aparece erro nenhum mas os dados que irao aparecer na base de dados serão - '0000-00-00'.